# calling int function in main() to display current working day

Tags: java, function, calendar

I am very new to java and found the following code to get the number of working days excluding Saturdays and Sundays.

I need to know how I can call this function in `main()` to display `workDays` for the current month.

Thanks.

```
package mypkg;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class workrays {

    public static int getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        Calendar startCal;
        Calendar endCal;
        startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCal.setTime(startDate);
        endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCal.setTime(endDate);
        int workDays = 0;

        //Return 0 if start and end are the same
        if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() == endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() > endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
            startCal.setTime(endDate);
            endCal.setTime(startDate);
        }

        do {
            startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY
            && startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                ++workDays;
            }
        } while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() < endCal.getTimeInMillis());

        return workDays;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(Date startDate, Date endDate);
        System.out.println(workdays);       
    }
}
```

Comment: When dealing with date calculations represented as `Date` or `Calendar` it is also important to consider what you intend if the values (which are really millisecond-precision timestamps) are not the same time within the day.  This is non-trivial and you must define it precisely if you don't want any surprising answers.  In your case a start-date of, say, 2/22/2013 08:00 and an end-date of 2/22/2013 17:00 returns zero, but it could be argued that the result should be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`. Second, you need to create the `Date`s instances before sending it to your `getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates` function. Third, you need to store the result of the `getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates` function in a local variable and then use it. In order to create the `Date`s, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        Date startDate = sdf.parse("2013-02-20");
        Date endDate = sdf.parse("2013-02-22");
        int workdays = getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(startDate, endDate);
        System.out.println(workdays);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There's an error somewhere. Check the stacktrace to find it");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

---

Based on your comment, you can create another function that returns a `Date` instance with the value of the 1st date by sending a `Date`:

```
public static Date getFirstDateOfMonth(Date aDate) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(aDate);
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Date endDate = new Date(); //current date/time
   Date startDate = getFirstDateOfMonth(endDate);
   int workdays = getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(startDate, endDate);
   System.out.println(workdays);
}
```

Comment: i want to set start date to 1st of the current month and end date to the date today.. is it possible so that in main it displays the working day for the current month

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the references like below:

```
Date startDate = new Date();
Date endDate = new Date();
getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(startDate, endDate);
```

or One Liner:

```
getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(new Date(), new Date());
```

Of course you have to provide values for your start and end dates while creating them, usually with a `java.util.Calendar`. You can also achieve it using Date methods but they are deprecated.

**Edit:**

This is how you manipulate `java.util.Date` using methods from [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Date startDate = new Date();//current date in milliseconds
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Comment: use methods from Calendar class toset the date.:)

Comment: is it possible to extract month/year from new date(); so i can put startDate = (year+"-"+month+"1) so each time it will pick 1st of the current month

Comment: cal.set(Calendar.Date, 1); error in this line :Date cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: it should be cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1). refer to the API of calendar that i included in the answer .. :)

Comment: Thanks getting the desired resuld:)

Comment: i have used int month = cal.get(cal.MONTH)+1;
       int year = cal.get(cal.YEAR);
       Date startDate = sdf.parse(year+"-"+month+"-1");